# Is this grammar right associative (why?)

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages

Given a grammar as follows:

$\left<stmt\right> \rightarrow \left<id\right> = \left<expr\right>$

$\left<const\right> \rightarrow A | B$

$\left<expr\right> \rightarrow \left<term\right> \times \left<expr\right> | \left<term\right>$

$\left<term\right> \rightarrow \left<factor\right> + \left<term\right> | \left<factor\right>$

$\left<factor\right> \rightarrow (\left<expr\right>) | \left<id\right>$

I think this grammar is right associative because it expands on the right. Where I am confused is it can be expanded using other non-terminals on the left. For example,

$\left<expr\right> \rightarrow \left<term\right> \times \left<expr\right> | \left<term\right>$

Could be expanded via $\left<term\right>$ on the left, I think. Does this make the associativity ambiguous? Assuming it could be ambiguous, how would I fix this to make the grammar completely right associative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left<expr\right> \to \left<term\right>×\left<expr\right> | \left<term\right>$

could certainly expand $\left<term\right>$. But the operator in that expansion (if there is one) is certainly not $×$; it would have to be $+$. So associativity doesn't apply, since associativity is only about expressions involving two of the same operator.

So yes, in both operator productions in that grammar, the operator is right-associative.